# Convert a list into a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

In Python, I have this list:

`[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]`

and I want to convert it into a list of strings, like:

`['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']`

This was my attempt:

```
val = [0,1]

['{x}{y}{z}'.format(x=x,y=y,z=z) for x in val for y in val for z in val]
```

But in some cases, the length of the string e.g.'001' may be variable (e.g. '01101') so it is frustrating editing this part `'{x}{y}{z}'.format(x=x,y=y,z=z)` each time

How can I do that?

Comment: `["".join(str(j) for j in i) for i in list_of_tuples]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using for loops and concatenation:

```py
arr1 = [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]

arr2 = []
for ind in range(len(arr1)):
    arr2.append("")
    for n in arr1[ind]:
        arr2[ind] += str(n)

print(arr2)
```

While this is a very simple and readable approach, there are other ways to do this that take up less space and have slightly more complex implementations, such as [@Olvin Roght's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68565543/10824407#comment121174788_68565543).

Comment: When generator expressions became complex?) Your solution is okay, but it's more generic *(in python)* to iterate over values rather than retrieve value by index. (`for el1 in arr1: ... for n in el1`)

Comment: In my experience those types of expressions arent rly taught in introductory python courses so i just wanted to use a simple implementation of looping by index but i agree that your solution is easier

Comment: [That](https://tio.run/##Rc1BCgIxDAXQfU/xmVWLo/h1I8KcZOhCULEgndCpC09fG600ZBF@Hom882OJx5OkUp5rJibMdj9C241oI9vInrKl7Jbdsls26029f9D73pj7kpBfghChX88GtXS/u4jc4tUOg/tmCoOyqn/qL@ctPTYT1pxscKV8AA)'s what I've told about.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the more simplifier version

```
a=[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
b=[]
for i in a:
    c=str(i)
    c=c.replace("(","")
    c=c.replace(")","")
    c=c.replace(",","")
    b.append(c)
print(b) # ['0 0 0', '0 0 1', '0 1 0', '0 1 1', '1 0 0', '1 0 1', '1 1 0', '1 1 1']
```

or in just one line:

```
b=[str(i).replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(",","") for i in a]
print(b) #['0 0 0', '0 0 1', '0 1 0', '0 1 1', '1 0 0', '1 0 1', '1 1 0', '1 1 1']
```